How to set default values for tm_a_mmrm
originally asked by https://github.com/statspeaking at https://github.com/insightsengineering/teal.modules.clinical/issues/846
When using tm_a_mmrm() we'd like to change some of the default values that are not arguments to the function. For example, we want weights_emmeans to be "equal" rather than "proportional" and show_relative to be "none" rather than "reduction". Is there a way to do this without creating a custom module? Thanks.
For example, we want weights_emmeans to be "equal" rather than "proportional" and show_relative to be "none" rather than "reduction". Is there a way to do this without creating a custom module? Thanks.
